# How to compare to Lists of different sizes to report the missing elements in a list?

Tags: java

Code to Check the Lists for Missing Values:

```
public List<String> getFlowChartStepsRemaining() throws Exception {
    List<String> remainingSteps = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> completedSteps = Arrays.asList(fcStepsCompleted);
    List<String> allSteps = Arrays.asList(getAllFlowChartStepByIDs());

    for (int i = 0; i < allSteps.size(); i++) //Traverse the master step ID list. 
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < completedSteps.size(); j++) //Go through the completed steps List. Find missing values based on position. 
        {
            if(Integer.parseInt(allSteps.get(i)) != Integer.parseInt(completedSteps.get(j)))
            {
                remainingSteps.add(allSteps.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    return remainingSteps;
}
```

Returns:
Steps Completed: [1, 2]Steps Remaining: [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]

Which essentially returns all the steps for this list, plus the four twice?

Comment: Your logic is flawed.  You're comparing every combination of numbers from the two lists, and some pairs aren't going to match even if both the numbers involved are somewhere in each list (just not where you're currently testing).  But if you find any pair that doesn't match, you add one of them to the `remainingSteps` list.  I'm not sure I explained that well.  I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<String> getAbsentElements(List<String>list1, List<String> list2){
    List<String> absent = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String temp1 : list1){
        if(!list2.contains(temp1)){
            absent.add(temp1);
        }
    }
    return absent;
}
```

this function can tell which elements are missing in `list2` but are part of `list1`

Answer (score 0):

You should have tried `removeAll` to remove all completed steps from the list of all steps:

```java
public List<String> getFlowChartStepsRemaining() throws Exception {
    List<String> allSteps = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getAllFlowChartStepByIDs());

    allSteps.removeAll(Arrays.asList(fcStepsCompleted));

    return allSteps;
}
```

Stream API could be used to implement the same functionality assuming that `getAllFlowChartStepByIDs()` return `String[]`:

```java
public List<String> getFlowChartStepsRemaining() throws Exception {
    // use set instead of list to remove possible duplicates
    Set<String> completedSteps = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(fcStepsCompleted));
    return Arrays.stream(getAllFlowChartStepByIDs())
                 .filter(id -> !completedSteps.contains(id)) // keep id not in the completedSteps
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a method in all Collection types that will do what you want without having to iterate.  It's called `removeAll`.  You'd use it like this:

```
public List<String> getFlowChartStepsRemaining() throws Exception {
    List<String> completedSteps = Arrays.asList(fcStepsCompleted);
    List<String> remainingSteps = Arrays.asList(getAllFlowChartStepByIDs());
    remainingSteps.removeAll(completedSteps);
    return remainingSteps;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use below complete code for getting the desired output.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ListRemovePOC {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Remaining steps are: " + ListContainsPOC.getFlowChartStepsRemaining());
    }

    public static List<String> getFlowChartStepsRemaining() throws Exception {
        List<String> completedSteps = Arrays.asList("1", "4", "6");
        List<String> allSteps = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
        List<String> remainingSteps = new ArrayList<String>(allSteps);
        remainingSteps.removeAll(completedSteps);
        return remainingSteps;
    }
}
```

Output:-

```java
Remaining steps are: [2, 3, 5]
```